# Why does comparison with "is" say values copied from one list to another are the same object?

Tags: python

```
L = [1, 2, 3]
M = L[:]
print(M is L, M[0] is L[0])
```

The output of the code above would be False True. 
I understand the first one is False because the two lists have different IDs, but why is the second one True? Don't they also have different IDs?

Comment: No. Why should they have different IDs?

Comment: It will be true because the first index of both list will be identical

Comment: If an object is immutable (and integers are immutable in Python), they can't be modified in-place -- any change to the value will result in a new and different id. Thus, it's always safe to copy them by making a new reference point to the same identity.

Comment: Even thinking that `[:]` produces a *copy* isn't correct, it produces a *slice*. And it certainly doesn't make a copy of the values within.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true for small integers [for the reason Anthon notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44603804/14122), but is true for mutable values as well, because copying a list copies the references -- every element of the new list points to the same identity as every element of the old list. The caveat is that with mutable values, it has side effects you may not want.

```
x = [ [], 2, 3 ]
y = x[:]
print(x[0] is y[0])       # this is true
x[0].append("hello")
print(y[0][0] == "hello") # this is also true, because both inner lists are the same object
```

This is the reason why [the `copy` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html), allowing `copy.deepcopy()` (to generate a new list with no shared elements), exists.

Answer (score 1):

No those `L[0]` and `M[0]` are two integers that have their ID based on their (immutable) value and first use. You will not get two different IDs for the number 1 during the lifetime of a program.

This happens only for smallish integers that Python cashes.

Answer (score 0):

is will return True if two variables point to the same object.
M is a reference to L. But M[0] and L[0] point to the same values.

Answer (score 0):

If two variables point to the same object, then `is` will return `True`. For (small) integers the ID depends mainly on their value and first use in the program, because integers are *immutable* (in Python). Any change to the value of an immutable object will result in a different ID, and thus the integer `1`, in this case, will only have one id during the program's run.